# How do I put elements in a list with custom variables as parameters?

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple console TEXT RPG. However, when i run the function, nothing is added to the items list. Am I doing something wrong?

```
internal class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BasicStatus();
            ShowInventory();
        }

        static void BasicStatus()
        {
            Inventory inventory = new();

            Item weap1 = new Item("Old Sword", "ATK", 2, "Common");
            Item armo1 = new Item("Iron Armor", "DEF", 5, "Uncommon");

            inventory.GetItem(weap1);
            inventory.GetItem(armo1);
        }

        static void ShowInventory()
        {
            Inventory inventory = new();
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("[ITEM LIST]");

            foreach (var Item in inventory.items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"- {Item.Name} | {Item.Type} +{Item.Effect} | {Item.Info}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Effect { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }

        public Item(string name, string type, int effect, string info)
        {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
            Effect = effect;
            Info = info;
        }
    }

    public class Inventory
    {
        public List<Item> items;

        public Inventory()
        {
            items = new List<Item>();
        }

        public void GetItem(Item item)
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }
}
```

I want two items to be printed in the foreach function. When I checked using Console.WriteLine(inventory.items.Count);, I found out that there was no element in the 'items' list.

Comment: Right before the `foreach` you initialize the `Inventory` with `new`. So at this point the list is empty. Side-note: you should not name your method `GetItem` if it actually _adds_ something to a list.

Comment: You create a completely new `Inventtory` in `ShowInventory`. You should pass that one you created before instead, e.g. by creating it in your `main`-function and providing that instance to both functions.

Comment: Let BasicStatus return the Inventory instead of void and then send that to ShowInventory as a parameter and use that instead of creating a new. Yeh, and also GetItem seems likte a bad name for AddItem.

Comment: Btw.: a function that *adds* items to something shouldn't be called *Get*Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void BasicStatus()
    {
        Inventory inventory = new();

        Item weap1 = new Item("Old Sword", "ATK", 2, "Common");
        Item armo1 = new Item("Iron Armor", "DEF", 5, "Uncommon");

        inventory.GetItem(weap1);
        inventory.GetItem(armo1);
    }
```

This creates a new inventory and adds some items to this inventory. But as soon as the method returns this inventory is lost, since it is declared as a local variable. `ShowInventory` then *creates a new inventory*, and this is of course empty when it has been created.

The simplest way to fix this is to declare the inventory as static, and use this in all other methods:

```
static Inventory inventory = new();
static void BasicStatus()
    {
        ...
```

But this is not something I would recommend. You should avoid mutable static objects as much as possible. My recommendation would be to create a class to manage the state of the game. I would expect the main method to basically look something like

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var game = new Game();
        game.Run();
    }
```

You should probably also create classes for things like "Player" and other concepts relevant for your game. Finally, please consider how you are naming your classes and methods. I would really have expected `GetItem(Item item)` to retrieve an item from the inventory. If it *adds* items to the inventory it should be called `AddItem`. The player might have a command to take an item, but that is a separate context.